# Beautiful Soup web scraping complex html for data

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Ok so I'm working on a self-directed term project for my college programming course. My plan is to scrape different parts of the [overwatch league website](https://overwatchleague.com/en-us) for stats etc, save them in a db and then pull from that db with a discord bot. However, I'm running into issues with the website itself. [Here's a screenshot of the html for the standings page](http://prntscr.com/rgy6mh).

As you can see it's quite convoluted and hard to navigate with the repeated div and body tags and I'm pretty sure it's dynamically created. My prof recommended I find a way to isolate the rank title on the top of the table and then access the parent line and then iterate through the siblings to pull the data such as the team name, position etc into a dictionary for now. I haven't been able to find anything online that helps me, most websites don't provide enough information or are out of date.

Here's what I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import link
import re
import pprint

url = 'https://overwatchleague.com/en-us/standings'

response = requests.get(url).text

page = BeautifulSoup(response, features='html.parser')



# for stat in page.find(string=re.compile("rank")):
#     statObject = {
#         'standing' : stat.find(string=re.compile, attrs={'class' : 'standings-table-v2styles__TableCellContent-sc-3q1or9-6 jxEkss'}).text.encode('utf-8')
#     }

# print(page.find_all('span', re.compile("rank")))  

# for tag in page.find_all(re.compile("rank")):
    # print(tag.name)

print(page.find(string=re.compile('rank')))

"""
# locate branch with the rank header,
# move up to the parent branch
# iterate through all the siblings and 
# save the data to objects
"""
```

The comments are all failed attempts and all return nothing. the only line not commented out returns a massive json with a lot of unnecessary information which does include what I want to parse out and use for my project. I've [linked it as a google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hdAEbot6H3AjDKc8HtCAj4XvnBumHN1SyaelAcr92hM/edit?usp=sharing) and highlighted what I'm looking to grab.

I'm not really sure how else to approach this at this point. I've considered using selenium however I lack knowledge of javascript so I'm trying to avoid it if possible. Even if you could comment with some advice on how else to approach this I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have noticed, your data is in JSON format. It is embedded in a script tag directly in the page so it's easy to get it using [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup). Then you need to parse the json to extract all the tables (corresponding to the 3 tabs) :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = 'https://overwatchleague.com/en-us/standings'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
script = soup.find("script",{"id":"__NEXT_DATA__"})

data = json.loads(script.text)

tabs = [
    i.get("standings")["tabs"]
    for i in data["props"]["pageProps"]["blocks"] 
    if i.get("standings") is not None
]

result = [
    { i["title"] : i["tables"][0]["teams"] }
    for i in tabs[0]
]

print(json.dumps(result, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

The above code gives you a dictionnary, the keys are the title of the 3 tabs and the value is the table data

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even realize it was already embedded in the page but that makes a lot of sense now.